# 2010 Honda Odyssey clip holding trim panel below doors

Tags: honda, odyssey, trim, clips

I have been repairing rust and when taking off the side trim below the door, some of the clips are missing or broken. This is the trim that runs along the entire bottom from wheel to wheel. I'd like to repair these but have not been able to find the part. Does anyone know what these might be called or where they might be obtained?

[image: A]
[image: B]
[image: C]
[image: D]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

These are called [Honda molding clips with sealer](https://www.clipsandfasteners.com/Honda-Moulding-Clips-With-Sealer-91513-TK8-A01-p/a22443.htm) ... part number from the website is: 91513-TK8-A01b ... Or they can be called [Honda Body Side Molding Clip](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/find/honda-body-side-molding-clip.c5934), where the part number is: O5030424398MTC.  I found both of these through [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=honda+body+molding+clip+replacement).